# Search a word inside post_content specifically on H1 tag

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

As Title implies, Search the value inside the variable of $word inside the  tag of column post_title content.

```
$word = test;
$pQuery = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_content LIKE  %s",'<h1>%'.$word.'%</h1>'), ARRAY_A)
```

```
ID post_title post_content
1  Hello      <h1>This is a post</h1> <p>This is a description of a post to test if the query is working</p> <h1>Found me test</h1>
2  World      <p>This is a description of a post to test if the query is working</p>
```

The query should view the data of of this ID

```
1 - Hello - <h1>This is a post</h1> <p>This is a description of a post to test if the query is working</p> <h1>Found me test</h1>
```

Comment: If you want your question reopened, check the "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening." box rather than adding remarks about (one of three) close voters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably won't work.

1. You need to use [$wpdb->esc_like()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/) on the search-term text with `%` wildcards in it, or prepare will garble your query.

   ```php
   $wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_content LIKE  %s",
       $wpdb->esc_like( '<h1>%'.$word.'%</h1>' )
   );
   ```
2. You need to search for  `'%<h1>%'.$word.'%</h1>%'` because your `<h1>` tag isn't at the beginning or the end of your post content. Put `%` at the beginning and end of your search term.
3. @tadman pointed out that your search won't work if your `<h1>` tags contain attributes. There's nothing you can do about that within the confines of SQL's LIKE filter.
4. If your post contains more than one `<h1>` tag your search term will consider words in the entire range between the first and last one.
5. This will be *very* slow.

There's an old slogan "If you solve a problem with a regular expression, now you have two problems". Let's modify that: "If you solve a problem with SQL's LIKE, now you have two and a half problems".

Point 4 could be a problem if your users are not tolerant of glitches.

You may want to consider a search plugin like Relevanssi for this kind of application.

Comment: Tried this code but it doesn't work. The result is empty.

Comment: A good troubleshooting approach is to use a MySQL client like phpmyadmin or HeidiSQL or something.  Try the query you think you want to run and make sure you get the results you want. Then look at the output from `->prepare()` and convice yourself it's the same query you tested manually.  **And, please keep in mind that cutting-and-pasting from StackOverflow without also understanding the code is a big problem in our trade.**

Comment: Yes, I know and thank you for the suggestion, i will try to do trial-and-error test on this one. I think if i tweak some things in the code you provide i can find the answer.